# SUMIF Help - Works and then dont

Tags: google-sheets, sumifs

=SUMIFS(M10:M999; B10:B999; ">=1/1/22"; B10:B999; "<=31/12/22")

Above line is to sum up my result of M10:M999 in the date in B column is adressed to 2022.
But all in column M has this line of code;
=IFS(AND(L10="W"; D10="Long");(H10-G10)*F10; AND(L10="L"; D10="Long");(H10-G10)*F10; AND(L10="BE");"0"; AND(L10="W"; D10="Short");(G10-H10)*F10; AND(L10="L"; D10="Short");(G10-H10)*F10)

Which spits out either a positive or negative amount of DKK (or 0).
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJ0pM.png)
Image shows 2022 and 2023.

When swapping the date to 2023 in either row in the B column, 2022 row starts working again and the 2023 row stops working.

Can someone help me?

[image]
I hope the above image helps bring some clarity to my issue.
The "Gain" row on far right, is the one giving me a headache.

If I change the date on "#8" > It will show the answer in 2022 Gains but will give me the error in 2023.

Comment: Could you share a sample sheet to see how is everything distributed?

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Post has been edited.

Answer (score 0):

** SOLVED **

My bad, I had an open order that wasn't showing a result cuz' the order in my sheet hadn't been close yet, now it works since the order has been closed and I filled in the missing part.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).